# How do you return focus to the document after window.confirm on Edge?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

After calling...

```
window.confirm("hello");
```

...Microsoft Edge does not return focus to the document.  I assume the same obtains for `window.alert();` and `window.prompt();`.

Is there a work around?

Comment: You might want to try to think about how to phrase this so that it contains a question - otherwise, it's not really on-topic as it reads more like a bug report.

Comment: Okay.  Done.  Please remove -1

Comment: Do you have sample code that behaves differently in Edge than Chrome or Firefox? How are you determining focus has been lost or restored?

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
document.focus();
```

called after the dialog returns will resolve this issue.